# PHP preg_match_all capture all patterns at front of string not mid string

Tags: php, regex

given the subject

```
AB: CD:DEF: HIJ99:message packet - no capture
```

I have crafted the following regex to capture correctly the 2-5 character targets which are all followed by a colon.

```
/\s{0,1}([0-9a-zA-Z]{2,5}):\s{0,1}/
```

which returns my matches even if erronious spaces are added before or after the targets

```
[0] => AB
[1] => CD
[2] => DEF
[3] => HIJ99
```

However, if the message packet contains a colon in it anywhere, for example

```
AB: CD:DEF: HIJ99:message packet no capture **or: this either**
```

it of course includes `[4] => or` in the resulting set, which is not desired.  I want to limit the matches to a consecutive set from the beginning, then once we lose concurrency, stop looking for more matches in the remainder

**Edit 1:** 
Also tried `^(\s{0,1}([0-9a-zA-Z]{2,5}):\s{0,1}){1,5}` to force checking from the beginning of the string for multiple matches, but then I lose the individual matches

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => AB: CD:DEF: HIJ99:
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => HIJ99:
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => HIJ99
    )
```

**Edit 2:** 
keep in mind the subject is not fixed.

```
AB: CD:DEF: HIJ99:message packet - no capture
```

could just as easily be

```
ZY:xw:VU:message packet no capture or: this either
```

for the matches we are trying to pull,  with the subject being variable as well.  Just trying to filter out the chance of matching a ":" in the message packet

Comment: Would it be enough to just edit the regex to match upper case character only? /\s{0,1}([0-9A-Z]{2,5}):\s{0,1}/

Comment: define a repetition for your pattern: `/(\s?([0-9a-zA-Z]{2,5}):\s?){0,4}/` for 0 to 4 repetitions

Comment: @typoheads could be upper or lower

Comment: @SBH - that adds all sorts of mess, but did an edit with your idea.  It is possible that there will be more matches than 0-4 though, and if the number is less, it will still grab the inline match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `\G` to do a consecutive string match.

```
$str = 'AB: CD:DEF: HIJ99:message packet no capture or: this either';
preg_match_all('/\G\s*([0-9a-zA-Z]{2,5}):\s*/', $str, $m);
print_r($m[1]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => AB
    [1] => CD
    [2] => DEF
    [3] => HIJ99
)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kH8oV5/3)

Comment: Brilliant...  first time using \G

Comment: final edit (just in case a leading space) `\G\s*([0-9a-zA-Z]{2,5}):\s*`   much obliged

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$str = 'AB: CD:DEF: HIJ99:message packet no capture or: this either';
preg_match_all('/(?<![^:]{7})([0-9a-zA-Z]{2,5}):/', $str, $m);
print_r($m);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => AB:
            [1] => CD:
            [2] => DEF:
            [3] => HIJ99:
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => AB
            [1] => CD
            [2] => DEF
            [3] => HIJ99
        )

)
```

Comment: am getting `Compilation failed: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length at offset 11` when I drop that code in.  disecting it

Comment: I think I see where you are going with that, but keep in mind the incoming subject could just as easily be `ZY:xw:VU:message packet no capture or: this either`

Comment: @Dave: that's strange, the lookbehind is fixed length here, and it works fine for me.